# for loop iterates only once

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I have a clients array of objects, so i use for loop to iterates over it
I have clients.lenght = 2, but it's iterates only 1. And i don't have variable scope problem here. Just don't get it why it happens.
**Code**

```
socket.on('idleDisconnectAllClient', function(receivedData) {
    LOG("idleDisconnectAllClient");

    var clientIndex = findMainIndexByDataBaseID(receivedData.dataBaseID);
    if (clientIndex != -1) {
        console.log('clients lenght', clients[clientIndex].data.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < clients[clientIndex].data.length; i++) {
            var client = clients[clientIndex].data[i];
            client.disconnect();

            console.log('client ' + i);
        }
    }
});
```

**Console**

```
2016-03-29 04:13:01 - idleDisconnectAllClient 
clients lenght 2         
client 0
```

Comment: I post a console answer. It's 2

Comment: Try `var clientsLen = clients[clientIndex].data.length;` and adjust your loop `for (var i = 0; i < clientsLen; i++)` and see if this helps

Comment: That helps! Thank you.

Comment: Is this question answered now?  Or is there still an open question?  If so, what is the current open question?

Comment: Can you log the values of i and of the array length after the for loop?

Comment: @jpaljasma but why doesn't OP solutions work? I don't see any different between your way and his way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jpaljasma - https://stackoverflow.com/users/2079695/jpaljasma 
helps me to understand the problem.

When i use - client.disconnect() it's just delete current client from clients array. So thats why my loop carried out only 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

you could iterate via the ES5 `forEach` construct:

```
clients[clientIndex].data.forEach(client => client.disconnect())
```

(disclaimer, this uses fat arrows from ES6, might not work on older node versions)